# Listview in dynamically created ListFragment doesn't appear

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listfragment

I'm currently developing an App where I want to use a bottom Navigation with multiple dynamically created Fragments.

Therefore I set up a test app to get used to these funtions.

The problem is now, if I create the ListFragment by a static XML the ListView is created correctly, but If I create it dynamically the ListView does not get displayed, only the BottomNavigation is displayed, nothing else.

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addFragment();
    }

    private void addFragment() {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        MyListFragment myListFragment = new MyListFragment();

        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, myListFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bottom_nav"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_nav"
        android:background="#808080"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

ListFragment:

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    CustomerAdapter customerAdapter;
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Customer customer = new Customer("Testcustomer","123456", "654321");
        customerAdapter = new CustomerAdapter(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()),R.layout.list_pack_item);
        listView = new ListView(getActivity());
        listView.setAdapter(customerAdapter);
        customerAdapter.add(customer);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        return listView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

CustomerAdapter:

```
public class CustomerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    List list = new ArrayList();
    public CustomerAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource ) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    public void add( @Nullable Customer object ) {
        super.add(object);
        list.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position ) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent ) {

        View row;
        row = convertView;
        CustomerHolder customerHolder;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_pack_item, parent, false);
            customerHolder = new CustomerHolder();

            customerHolder.tx_name = row.findViewById(R.id.tx_name);
            customerHolder.tx_intern = row.findViewById(R.id.tx_intern);
            customerHolder.tx_extern = row.findViewById(R.id.tx_extern);
            row.setTag(customerHolder);
        } else {
            customerHolder = (CustomerHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        Customer customer = (Customer) this.getItem(position);
        customerHolder.tx_name.setText(customer.getName());
        customerHolder.tx_intern.setText("Internal Number: " + customer.getMyCustomerNumber());
        customerHolder.tx_extern.setText("Supplier Number: " + customer.getSupplierNumber());

        return row;
    }

    static class CustomerHolder {
        TextView tx_name, tx_intern, tx_extern;
    }
}
```

Customer Class

```
public class Customer {

    private String name;
    private String supplierNumber;
    private String myCustomerNumber;

    public Customer(String name, String supplierNumber, String myCustomerNumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.supplierNumber = supplierNumber;
        this.myCustomerNumber = myCustomerNumber;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSupplierNumber() {
        return supplierNumber;
    }

    public void setSupplierNumber(String supplierNumber) {
        this.supplierNumber = supplierNumber;
    }

    public String getMyCustomerNumber() {
        return myCustomerNumber;
    }

    public void setMyCustomerNumber(String myCustomerNumber) {
        this.myCustomerNumber = myCustomerNumber;
    }
}
```

If there is any further information or code needed please let me know!

Additionally: I need to create the fragments dynamically in order to replace them, am I correct?

Comment: How do you know that there is a problem if you are not aware of it? Like, atleast you could tell us what is happening that makes you think that there is something wrong so that we know where to look

Comment: Just updated the description, sorry.

Comment: Have you tried setting a layout params to the listview?

Comment: I just tried adding this: listView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
after: listView = new ListView(getContext());
and before: listView.setAdapter(customerAdapter);

Comment: But the Listview is still not being displayed.